# Create new string variable with partial matching of another

Tags: regex, stata

I am using Stata 15 and I would like to create a new string variable based on the contents of another.

Consider the following toy variable:

```
clear

input str18 string
"a b c"        
"d e f"
"g h i"    
end
```

I know I can use the `regexm()` function to extract all occurrences of `a`, `b`, `d` and `g`:

```
generate new = regexm(string, "a|c|d|g")

list

|string    new |
|--------------|
|  a b c     1 |
|  d e f     1 |
|  g h i     1 |
```

However, how can I get the following?

```
|string    new   |
|----------------|
|  a b c     a c |
|  d e f     d   |
|  g h i     g   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ustrregexra()` function to eliminate any occurrences of the matching  characters:

```
clear

input str5 string
"a b c"        
"d e f"
"g h i"    
end

generate wanted = ustrregexra(string, "[^a|c|d|g]", " ")

list

     +-----------------+
     | string   wanted |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  a b c    a   c |
  2. |  d e f    d     |
  3. |  g h i    g     |
     +-----------------+
```

If you want to eliminate the remain spaces:

```
replace wanted = strtrim(stritrim(wanted))

     +-----------------+
     | string   wanted |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  a b c      a c |
  2. |  d e f        d |
  3. |  g h i        g |
     +-----------------+
```