# Extract string pattern in new variable based on other string variable

Tags: regex, stata, string-matching

Consider the following variable:

```
clear

input str18 string
"abc bcd cde"        
"def efg fgh"
"ghi hij ijk"    
end
```

I can use the `regexm()` function to extract all occurrences of `abc`, `cde` and `def`:

```
generate new = regexm(string, "abc|cde|def")

list

|string          new |
|--------------------|
|  abc bcd cde     1 |
|  def efg fgh     1 |
|  ghi hij ijk     0 |
```

How can I get the following?

```
|string            wanted  |
|--------------------------|
|  abc bcd cde     abc cde |
|  def efg fgh     def     |
|  ghi hij ijk             |
```

This question is an extension of the one answered here:

- [Create new string variable with partial matching of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429917/create-new-string-variable-with-partial-matching-of-another)

Comment: The term _column_ is appropriate within Stata only for columns of a matrix or table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution using a regular expression:

```
clear

input str18 string
"abc bcd cde"        
"def efg fgh"
"ghi hij ijk"    
end

generate wanted = ustrregexra(string, "(\b((?!(abc|cde|def))\w)+\b)", " ")  
replace wanted = strtrim(stritrim(wanted))

list

     +-----------------------+
     |      string    wanted |
     |-----------------------|
  1. | abc bcd cde   abc cde |
  2. | def efg fgh       def |
  3. | ghi hij ijk           |
     +-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I read this as your

1. Having a list of allowed words.
2. Wanting the words in a string that occur among the allowed words.

It is fashionable to seek a fancy regular expression solution for such problems, but your example at least yields to a plain loop over the words that exist. Be aware, however, that `inlist()` has advertised limits.

```
clear

input str18 string
"abc bcd cde"        
"def efg fgh"
"ghi hij ijk"    
end

generate wanted = "" 

generate wc = wordcount(string) 
summarize wc, meanonly 

quietly forvalues j = 1/`r(max)' { 
    replace wanted = wanted + " " + word(string, `j') if inlist(word(string, `j'), "abc", "cde", "def")
} 

replace wanted = trim(wanted) 

list 

     +----------------------------+
     |      string    wanted   wc |
     |----------------------------|
  1. | abc bcd cde   abc cde    3 |
  2. | def efg fgh       def    3 |
  3. | ghi hij ijk              3 |
     +----------------------------+
```